# Finding long axis of irregular polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I need some help in how to find the long axis of an irregular shaped ellipse using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have found the centroid but don't know how to determine the longest distance.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management) tool.

Use the 'Convex Hull' option.

This will create several new fields:

MBG_Length will give you the distance between the farthest points (antipodes)

The MBG_APOD points will give you the coordinates of the new antipodal line

Further reference: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000

Comment: It should be noted that the Convex Hull option is only available with an ArcInfo license.  If you don't have this license, then this tool may not be sufficient.

Comment: This link works for all license levels
http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=3D230972-1422-2418-34A5-2F3FFF97C238

Answer (score 2):

I think at basic license this can be done by using **"Rectangle By Area"** Command as below is the comparison..

[image: MBG]