# Determining the longest side of polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, polyline-creation, length, maximum

Is there a possibility to determine the longest side of a polygon with QGIS?

As I need to do that for hundreds of polygons I would prefer an automized method (like a plugin).

So far my idea was:

- transforming a polygon into a line
- cut it on the vertices
- measure the length
- here I became stuck, how to become the longest line without checking the whole bunch of lines one by one?

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27531/finding-the-long-axis-of-an-irregular-polygon

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

If you can use PostGIS, try using the [`ST_LongestLine()`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_LongestLine.html) function like this:

```sql
SELECT ST_LongestLine(geom, geom)
FROM mypolytable;
```

This will find the longest line that can be drawn within each polygon geometry. Note that I'm using this function that references the *same* geometry column `geom` twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The function you mentioned returns the 2-dimensional longest line points of two geometries but Im looking for the longest line of a single polygon. Am i wrong? Anybody else an idea??

Comment: Two geometries is actually *one* geometry when you reference the same geometry twice, as I have described. Did you try it?

Comment: @MikeT It is cool function I did not know exists, but I guess OP needs longest segment of polygon boundary which is something very different from what this function returns.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'poly'* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Proceed with the ["Polygons to lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygons-to-lines)

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Explode lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisexplodelines)

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** Use the ["Extract by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) with the following expression (includes the [`maximum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#maximum) function)

```
$length = maximum($length, "id")
```

[image: step_3]

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'polygons'* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Proceed with the ["Polygons to lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygons-to-lines)

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Extract vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices) two times, it will be important for the next step

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** Make use of ["Join by lines (hub lines)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#join-by-lines-hub-lines) between the two layers with vertices. Afterwards the application of the ["Fix geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries), ["Remove null geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#remove-null-geometries) and ["Delete duplicate geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisdeleteduplicategeometries) is probable

[image: step_3]

**Step 4.** Employ the ["Extract by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) (`are within` for geometrical predicate) between the Results of the *Step 3* and *Step 1*

[image: step_4]

**Step 5.** Use the ["Extract by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) with the following expression (includes the [`maximum`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#maximum) function)

```
$length = maximum($length, "id")
```

[image: step_5]