# Identify the length and orientation of the features in P2 relative to features in P2? (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, measurements, length

I try to measure the maximal length and orientation of features in one shapefile (S1) relative to polygons in another shapefile 2 (S2). My goal is to evaluate the spreading of patches of beetle-induced tree mortality from one year (S1) to another (S2).

I can measure near distances and position (angle) of the feature S2 to S1 using NEAR Tool http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm.

To measure the length and orientation of shapefiles in S2, I can apply Mimimum Bounding Geometry, Rectangle_by_Width, as mentioned here: [MBG_Orientation: ranges from 0-180, instead of 0-360? (ArcGIS, Minimal Bounding Geometry)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239763/mbg-orientation-ranges-from-0-180-instead-of-0-360-arcgis-minimal-bounding).

However, the resulting orientation of the "rectange_by_width" ranges from 0-180, and it is not relative to the polygons in S1. The NEAR_ANGLE, derived from NEAR Tool, does not reflect the orientation of the individual polygons.

Combining these two tools I can identify the relative locations of individual features towards polygons from S1, and the length of polygons of the S2.

Is there any other way how to record also the orientation of the spots S2?

[image]

Comment: A start would be to take a look at Minimum Bounding Geometry, Rectangle By Width. You can then split the rectangle into separate lines and get length and directions. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm

Comment: Cool, thank you for suggestion ! following your advice I found this  post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27531/finding-long-axis-of-irregular-polygon-using-arcgis-desktop